# Is it possible to change (gone) to (been) and the answer still be correct?

Tags: past-participles, been-vs-gone

Here is a question

> Put the verbs in brackets into a suitable tense form
> ____ you _____ (go) to your dentist recently?

Typical answer: **Have you gone to your dentist recently?**

I noticed many users change *gone* to *been*.
I think those have not the right to make such changes simply the option is **(go)** and not **(be)**

Am I right or not?

I know (have gone) = went but not returned yet or in his way coming back whereas (have been) = went and came back

Answer (score 2):

Been is a form of the verb "be". [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be) gives this meaning under **be**: "to come or go", with examples "has already been and gone", "has never been to the circus", so you can see it's normally used in the perfect tense "have been"/"has been".

Therefore if you're asked to use a form of the verb "go" you can't use a form of the verb "be", any more than you can use "come", "travel", "walk", or other words whose meaning might be similar but which are not what you are asked to do.

Comment: Thank you very much